# hovering (migration of .ease(d3.easeBounceOut) to .ease("easeBounceOut"))

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to convert a code made in d3.js v5 to version 3 of d3.js. I do everything possible to convert the original code made in

version 5:

http://plnkr.co/edit/w8v0Iz6Fg3rJTyxeXKca?p=preview

to version 3.

http://plnkr.co/edit/NjQFVtDHhglt1NT4sn5s?p=preview

I would like to have exactly the same result as version 5, but currently the hovering effect does not work for me. I am doing something wrong?.
thank you very much.

this is the code of version 5.

```
    CircleNumber=Math.round(15)
    const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",250).attr("height",250);
    const data = Array.from(Array(CircleNumber).keys());


    function emananting(){
              console.log('emanting!!')
                svg.selectAll('circle.emanting')
                 .each((d,i,g)=>{
                   console.log(d,i,g)
                  let index = i;
                  d3.select(g[i])
                    .transition()
                  .duration((d,i)=>{
                       return 5000;
                     })
                    .delay((d,i)=>{
                       return index*1000; 
                      })
                  .attr('opacity',0)
                  .attr('r',50).remove();
                });
    }
    const radialGradient = svg.append("defs")
                              .append("radialGradient")
                              .attr("id", "radial-gradient");

    radialGradient.append("stop")
                      .attr("offset", "0%")
                      .attr("stop-color", "#f4425f");

    radialGradient.append("stop")
                    .attr("offset", "100%")
                    .attr("stop-color", "orange");
    //background
      svg.append('rect')
         .classed('background', true)
         .attr('width', 200)
         .attr('height', 200)
         .attr('x', 25)
         .attr('y', 25)
         .attr('fill', 'black')
         .attr('opacity', 0.5);
    // Outer 
    svg.append("circle")
       .classed('OuterCircle', true)
       .attr("cx",125)
       .attr("cy",125)
       .attr("r",40)
       .attr("fill","url(#radial-gradient)")
       .attr('gradient',()=>{return })
       .attr("stroke","orange")    
       .on('mouseover',(d,i,g)=>{
         console.log(g)
            d3.select(g[i]).transition().ease(d3.easeBounceOut).duration(500).attr("r",60)
         })
       .on('mouseout', (d,i,g)=>{
           d3.select(g[i]).transition().ease(d3.easeBounceOut).duration(500).attr("r",40)
         });
    // Inner
    svg.append('circle')
       .classed('InnerCircle',true)
       .attr('r',20)
       .attr('stroke','yellow')
       .attr('fill','yellow')
       .attr('opacity',1)
       .attr('cx',125)
       .attr('cy',125)
       .on('mouseover',(d,i,g)=>{
            console.log('outercircle');
            console.log(g[i]);
            d3.select(g[i]).transition().ease(d3.easeBounceOut).duration(500).attr("r",35)
         })
       .on('mouseout', (d,i,g)=>{
           d3.select(g[i]).transition().ease(d3.easeBounceOut).duration(500).attr("r",20)
         });

    svg.selectAll('circle.emanting')
                    .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append('circle')
                .attr('class','emanting')
                    .attr('id', (d,i)=>{
                        return 'number' + i;
                                    })
                .attr('r',20)
                .attr('stroke','yellow')
                .attr('fill','none')
                    .attr('opacity',1)
                .attr('stroke-width',2)
                .attr('cx',125)
                .attr('cy',125);

    emananting();
```

In the versión of v3:

basically I have problems with the third attribute of the functions (g is always 0):

```
function(d,i,){ }
```

therefore where the third attribute `g` appears, I deleted it and I will always set the value of g globally.

```
var g=svg.selectAll('circle.emanting')[0]
```

and I have changed the animations of

```
d3.select(g[i]).transition().ease(d3.easeBounceOut).duration(500).attr("r",60)
```

to

```
d3.select(g[i]).transition().ease("easeBounceOut").duration(500).attr("r",35)
```

Comment: Both your plunker links are the same.

Comment: Excuse me! Done! @pmkro thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm still seeing both as using v5.

Comment: @pmkro check again please... the second link use v3 http://plnkr.co/edit/NjQFVtDHhglt1NT4sn5s?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[My plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jMsNYcSnGaoewXx6sMgr?p=preview) It wasn't referencing the selection correctly. I changed `d3.select(g[i])` to `d3.select(this)` and since `easeBounceOut` [doesn't seem to exist in v3](http://bl.ocks.org/hunzy/9929724), I changed it to `bounce`.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h5eu45jz/4/) Here is a fiddle with a single circle that transitions indefinitely. Uses a "recursive" function, that calls itself after the transition is over.

Comment: Thank you! you are a genious. but the animation of the circles was damaged

Comment: is a good idea `var g=svg.selectAll('circle.emanting')[0]` and remove third atributte g, where the animation is generated?

Comment: updated the link where the circle emanation works. Removed the function call and took the function internals and stuck it on the bottom of the emanating circle generation.

Comment: great! You are amazing. One last question, and I think I'll finish. Do you know how I can generate the effect of emanting, be infinite?

Comment: Ooo not sure about that one. Right now it takes 15 circles and transitions them, so once those are done its over. And you can't really create an infinitely long array.

Comment: `d3.select(g[i])` is a **correct** reference since the third argument is the node's group (v > 3).

Comment: Might be able to do [something like this](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/bf44061b1d443f455b3f857f82721372) for an infinite transition.

Comment: @yavg I added a fiddle to my answer with an infinite transition.

Comment: @pmkro Thank you very much for the effort, I have a question, why does only one circle appear making the animation? in the original link of version 5 several animated circles were generated. in your jsdfiddle only one.

Comment: @yavg I only included one as a proof of concept. 15 looks strange and requires a bit more tinkering. Play with some of the values and see what you like. This is a good way to learn.